How do I add 30-minute intervals to the django-grapelli TimeField?
I would like to add 30-minute time intervals in the Grappelli Django Theme. I have currently implemented the following code, but the time field is still showing hourly time intervals in the admin form I'm wanting to change. Have I missed anything out?
# myapp/widgets.py
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class CustomAdminTimeWidget(forms.TimeInput):
    template_name = 'admin/shifts/shift/custom_timepicker.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super().__init__(attrs, format='%H:%M')

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css',
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css',
            )
        }
        js = [
            'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
            'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js',
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js',
        ]

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        rendered = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        js = f'''
        <script>
        $(function() {{
            $('#id_{name}').timepicker({{
                stepMinute: 30,
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
            }});
        }});
        </script>
        '''
        return mark_safe(rendered + js)

# myapp/forms.py
from django import forms
from myapp.widgets import CustomAdminTimeWidget
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'time_field': CustomAdminTimeWidget(),
        }

# myapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.forms import MyModelForm

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)

<!-- templates/myapp/custom_timepicker.html -->
{% block widget %}
    <input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}" {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %} />
{% endblock %}

